# Professional knowledge base vs. penalty for deleting a downvoted question?

Tags: discussion

SO is trying to be a professional knowledge base. I couldn't agree more with that! But how is that in accordance with the fact that one gets penalized for deleting a question that received downvotes (only)? Even trying to delete a question with downvotes and just one non-accepted answer throws an alert, saying "Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?"

Doesn't this fall under "You can't have the cake and eat it?"

Comment: Instead of a yes/no question would you convert it to something like:  "What is the rationale behind this vexing contradiction".  This may prompt more useful answers than throwing out a worn adage for the higher ups to snipe at.

Comment: There is a trend of "anti-social" users asking questions (poorly), then deleting as soon as they get an answer. This wastes the time of answers and removes the question from the site. Anyway, if you're not doing it repeatedly, what's the problem?

Comment: @GayotFow - I *am* asking that, in the first paragraph. A bit of flexibility?

Comment: @DavidRobinson - Removing a poorly asked question keeps the knowledge base professional. And I'm not just asking for myself, I'm asking with the idea in mind that SO indeed should stay or become a professional knowledge base.

Comment: @FrankConijn That's kind of the point.. You shouldn't be asking "poorly asked" questions, and that is what the ban system is in place for. There is nothing professional about asking poor and/or lazy questions and then deleting them is there? Stack Overflow is not a forum. Personally, I've asked questions on many sites, including SO and some of those were even dumb questions. I have never had any problems with downvotes and questions bans whatsoever. If you are getting lots of downvotes and/or are questions banned then something is definitely wrong with your questions.

Comment: You don't give any links, so we can't really help you there.

Comment: @Seth - Read my reply to David Robinson's comment.

Comment: @FrankConijn I'm sorry, but your reply doesn't make much sense.. Penalized for asking bad questions keeps us professional..

Comment: @Seth - I'm not talking about getting penalized for asking bad questions. I'm talking about getting penalized for deleting bad questions.

Comment: Ahhh. I think that is where I missed the point. Sorry and thank you :)

Answer (score 10):

> But how is that in accordance with the fact that one gets penalized for deleting a question that received downvotes (only)?

It isn't. Because you're not really penalized for deleting a question that gets *nothing but downvotes*.*

You will, however, get penalized for posting questions that get downvoted - regardless of whether or not you delete them. You'll always get penalized for posting questions that have cost others' time and effort, regardless of whether that was in the form of answers or downvotes, **if the question does not go on to benefit anyone**. The penalties aren't huge, but if they're not offset by anything then you're gonna end up in trouble.

So, **make sure you're contributing valuable content to the site more often than you're contributing posts that just waste people's time!** Our time is a finite resource; we have to be careful about letting folks monopolize it.

There are entirely too many people who ask mediocre questions and then delete them as soon as they get an answer, thus ensuring that *no one* has the opportunity to ever benefit from the work invested answering them. We *have to* discourage such abuse.

If you want to avoid trouble, then:

- **Avoid asking questions that are already answered!** [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) is your friend...
- **Ask clear, well-written questions that focus on a specific problem.** [We have a handy guide to doing this...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- **If you make a mistake, *fix it!*** Don't assume that others will do it for you; there are more bad questions than there are folks with time to edit them.
- **Don't waste people's time!** If someone takes the time to help you, make sure their effort isn't wasted. The next person with the same problem should be able to find the answer by searching; make sure that they will.

<sup>*<sub>Ok, there are fairly obscure scenarios where this *will* penalize you, but they mostly involve accounts that have *nothing but deleted questions* - at some point, we just gotta stop the bleeding.</sub></sup>

Comment: You're stating: "There are entirely too many people who ask mediocre questions and then delete them as soon as they get an answer, thus ensuring that no one has the opportunity to ever benefit from the work invested answering them. We have to discourage such abuse." FC: I'd say: why spend time on mediocre questions anyway? Why just not let them go unanswered?

Comment: You're also stating: "Ok, there are fairly obscure scenarios where this will penalize you, but they mostly involve accounts that have nothing but deleted questions - at some point, we just gotta stop the bleeding." FC: A question that got two downvotes and no accepted answer, from someone with an account that received more up- than dowvotes (including star clicks), I can't find that "fairly obscure". Happens all the time, I'd say. But if I try to delete that question, I still get the warning as mentioned in my OP.

Answer (score 5):

It falls under the heading: **Think before you post**.

Make sure your *next* question won't require deleting. Learn how to post good questions instead.

I don't see why the warning conflicts with the goal. Good, quality questions are upvoted, bad questions are downvoted. If you want to not be question banned, you try to avoid getting your question downvoted.

Note that downvoted questions without answers are *deleted from the site automatically* after 30 days. Closed questions (other than duplicates) can be deleted even faster if they haven't been edited or received reopen votes.

Comment: That doesn't answer my primary question: how are those two matters in accordance with each other?

Comment: @FrankConijn: I don't see any conflict whatsoever. Downvoted questions are de-emphasised, people that ask bad questions repeatedly are question-banned. The system *works*, and we incentivise good, professional questions.

Comment: You really don't see any conflict whatsoever??

Comment: No, I fail to see where there is a conflict here.